Conda install does not recognize solver argument
I successfully installed libmamba but when I try to use it, for example -->
conda install --name myenv <package> --solver=libmamba -c conda-forge
I get:
conda: error: unrecognized arguments: --solver=libmamba
I'm currently running:
conda version : 4.12.0
conda-build version : 3.17.8
Do I need to update my conda? Or is there another issue?
I successfully installed libmamba -->
conda install -n base conda-libmamba-solver
but am having trouble setting it as the solver.

On Windows 11 (version 23H2), I have the same issue with conda 4.12.0.
Did you resolve it? I was trying to follow the steps here --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/78801173

I ended up doing something different for this install. The conclusion, after talking to several people, was that I needed to update my conda (https://www.anaconda.com/blog/a-faster-conda-for-a-growing-community). I would try that and see.
